# Winform application - error on getting Azure secret from KeyVault "DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials."

Tags: c#, azure, winforms, azure-keyvault

I have winform application written in c#. I am trying to fetch azure secrets from Azure KeyVault. I have written below function to fetch the secret.

```
    private async Task<string> GetSecretFromAzureKV(string secretName)
    {
        try
        {
            var keyVaultName = "my-Keyvault-name";
            var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";

            var credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), credentials);

            var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);

            return secret.Value.Value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

When I debug this solution I can see below error.
[image]

Also, note that I am not running it on Azure VM. The code is on my local machine.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your configuration file. What is the framework version of your app?

Comment: The app is failing to retrieve the user credentials.The code which you have set is using the default credentials (VS).Have you logged in to Azure account in Visual Studio?You need to login to the same azure subscription account where you have azure keyvault.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/f7ZM1fh.png)

Comment: I can't see an error, the debugger displays some static strings containing possible errors. Set your breakpoint at the `throw` statement to catch any exception. The exception due to the `DefaultAzureCredential` will only be raised by calling `GetSecretAsync` so I have no idea why you think you have an error based on where you are now in your displayed debug session. Please inspect any inner exception messages as well.

Comment: @Harshitha, Actually it will be standalone desktop application. User will be using .exe file of my application. And if user has access to Azure Keyvault, he should be able to fetch the secret by running application on his machine.

Comment: Check the value in `secret` variable under `GetRawResponse`

Comment: Iam able to retrieve the secret value with the same code.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/ioTHVYE.png).The only change I have done is add `();` after `DefaultAzureCredential`

Comment: Sorry it was typo. It was there in my code, but missed while copying here. When debugger hits line var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName); then it never returns response.

Comment: Iam getting the [warnings](https://i.imgur.com/EILndNs.png) same like you.As mentioned by @PeterBons do not worry about them.Still I can get the value even with warnings

Comment: @Harshitha Apart from this code, did you do configuration changes or any changes in Azure portal for granting access to winform application?

Comment: @IrshadFaras - No..I haven't done anything.Have you checked my first comment.Have you logged into the account?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Do you have Vault access policy access in Keyvault.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256048/discussion-between-irshad-faras-and-harshitha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how but replacing async method to sync worked for me.
Thanks @Harshita for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Key Vault, check whether you have the below configurations in `Access configuration`.

If you have `Vault access policy` you will be able to add the secrets and retrieve them without any issues.

***OR***

If you have `Azure role-based access control`, then you must have a Key Vault related role (`KeyVault Administrator` or `KeyVault Secret User`) assigned to service principle or user.

[image]

- And in `Access policies`, make sure you have access policy with your ID/Name and have `Get/List` Key/Secret permissions.

[image]

- Also check that your Key Vault Secret is Enabled.

[image]

> error on getting Azure secret from KeyVault "DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials."

Those are the default messages which will be shown in the `DefaultAzurecredential`.

[image]

- I am able to retrieve the Secret successfully even though I am getting the warnings.

[image]